# Google Cloud App: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Any spaces must be in the middle of a filename:

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm following the tutorial of how to deploy a new Google Cloud app to the tee.

I ran:

```
gcloud app deploy
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Any spaces must be in the middle of a filename:  ~/envs/hello_world/bin/activate
```

What could have gone wrong?

Comment: Same issue. Followed the tutorial running the exact commands they do, and it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when doing the tutorial it turned out I was adding an extra space when executing this command:

```
$ virtualenv --python python3 \ ~/envs/hello_world
```

Instead of:

```
$ virtualenv --python python3 \~/envs/hello_world
```

And that was causing all the trouble.  I also had to delete the hello_world directory and reclone it, then using the correct command (without the space) to get it working correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this issue myself. Drove me insane.

For me it was literally what it said - it doesn't like spaces on the beginning or end of files or folders. Follow the path that it reports in the error from your current directory, and find any folders or files with a space likely on the end. Get rid of it, all good.

It reported

```
INVALID_ARGUMENT: Any spaces must be in the middle of a filename: exec -l /bin/bash/google-cloud-sdk/lib/gcloud.py
```

and true enough, the "exec -l" folder was actually "exec -l ". You can even see that in the output on the error, I was just blind to it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are following the [Google App Engine Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/) for deploying you app. I have tested the documentation and the App was deployed successfully. It looks like you are trying to deploy the app from a virtual environment and either some of the files that used for deployment have an invalid name or some folders do. Names must contain only `letters` and `_` .

Try moving the `hello_world` folder, that contains all your App files for deployment, to the main directory and check that all the filenames are formed correctly. Then, try deploying again.

The question has very few information, so if what I have suggested to you didn't help. Please provide more information about the issue.