# gcloud return INVALID_ARGUMENT: Any spaces must be in the middle of a filename: when I try to app deploy my app

Tags: python, gcloud

When I try to run `gcloud app deploy`  I get in return error without some spcecific information which can help to locate problem:

```
descriptor:                  [/home/ilija/code/meezer/backend/app.yaml]
source:                      [/home/ilija/code/meezer/backend]
target project:              [mosh-marketplace-7eca5]
target service:              [default]
target version:              [20230319812345]
target url:                  [https://mosh-marketplace-7eca5.uc.r.appspot.com]
target service account:      [App Engine default service account]


Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  y

Beginning deployment of service [default]...
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
╠═ Uploading 0 files to Google Cloud Storage                ═╣
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
File upload done.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Any spaces must be in the middle of a filename:
```

Someone have idea how I can debug this?

I try to get some idea in official documentation and stakoverflow but I did`t dig anything useful till now.

I expect app to be deployed without this error.

Comment: Have you searched? For example this seems to suggest the error is correct: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53980788/google-cloud-app-error-gcloud-app-deploy-invalid-argument-any-spaces-must-b For debugging, I would start with looking at all your filename.  It *would* be nice if gcloud would tell you *which* file.

Answer (score 0):

I found reason for error: one folder had empty space inside the name. What means just loop through your directories and files and locate one with space in it. Correct and you should be good....